# How to group by and count values in my DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["App","Feature1", "Feature2","Feature3",
                           "Feature4","Feature5",
                           "Feature6","Feature7","Feature8"], 
                  data=[["SHA",0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0],
                        ["LHA",1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0],
                        ["DRA",0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
                        ["FRA",1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1],
                        ["BRU",0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
                        ["PAR",0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0],
                        ["AER",0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0],
                        ["SHE",0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]])
```

**UPDATE: (sorry I incorrectly formulated the expected result)**

I want to count the number of time that the value `1` appears for each feature:

```
Features   Count
Feature1   6
Feature2   7
...
```

I tried this:

```
df.groupBy("App").count()
```

But I do not get an expected output.

Comment: So need count only `0` values? Or need 2 column DataFrame ?

Comment: @jezrael: I need to count `1` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#remove column App, compare and get sum of Trues
a0 = df.drop('App', 1).eq(0).sum()
#a0 = df.set_index('App').eq(0).sum()

#alternative with select only Feature columns
#a0 = df.filter(like='Feature').eq(0).sum()

#alternative with select all columns without first
a0 = df.iloc[:, 1:].eq(0).sum()

print (a0)
Feature1    6
Feature2    7
Feature3    2
Feature4    2
Feature5    4
Feature6    6
Feature7    1
Feature8    7
dtype: int64
```

Similar for compare with `1`:

```
a1 = df.drop('App', 1).eq(1).sum()
#a1 = df.set_index('App').eq(1).sum()

#alternative
#a1 = df.filter(like='Feature').eq(1).sum()
#alternative
a1 = df.iloc[:, 1:].eq(1).sum()

print (a1)
Feature1    2
Feature2    1
Feature3    6
Feature4    6
Feature5    4
Feature6    2
Feature7    7
Feature8    1
dtype: int64
```

All together with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.value_counts.html):

```
a = df.drop('App', 1).apply(pd.value_counts).T.add_prefix('count_')
print (a)
          count_0  count_1
Feature1        6        2
Feature2        7        1
Feature3        2        6
Feature4        2        6
Feature5        4        4
Feature6        6        2
Feature7        1        7
Feature8        7        1
```

Or with list comprehension:

```
L = [df[x].value_counts() for x in df.columns.difference(['App'])]
a = pd.concat(L, 1).T.add_prefix('count_')
print (a)
          count_0  count_1
Feature1        6        2
Feature2        7        1
Feature3        2        6
Feature4        2        6
Feature5        4        4
Feature6        6        2
Feature7        1        7
Feature8        7        1
```

Comment: Thank you. This is nice. But sorry, see my update. I mistakenly created an incorrect expected output. Could you please update your answer? Sorry again.

Comment: No problem, I add more possible solutions. Good luck!

Comment: In your solution `a1 = df.iloc[:, 1:].eq(1).sum()` how can I put the names of colums of `a1` to `Feature` and `Count`?

Comment: Ah, I did it myself: `a1.columns = ["Features","Count"]`

Comment: Or `a1 = df.iloc[:, 1:].eq(1).sum().rename_axis('Feature').reset_index(name='Count')`

Answer (score 0):

Another way using melt:

First get long format data:

```
df_melt=pd.melt(df, id_vars='App', value_vars=['Feature%d'%(i) for i in range(1,9)], var_name='Features', value_name='value')
```

Then groupby `Features` and count the 1's:

```
df_melt.groupby('Features').sum().reset_index().rename(columns={'value':'count'})
```